# Не получается отловить событие у карты Air Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, календарь

Хотела реализовать следующий функционал: слева располагается статичная и всегда открытая карта, которая позволяет выбирать дату и подсвечивать ее, а в другом месте вывести выбранную дату, рисунок прилагаю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрала карту Air Datepicker, вывела карту на экран, стилизовала её. Хотела словить событие выбора даты, однако никак не получается это сделать. Код прилагается. 
Разметка:

```
    <div class="form__calendar">
        <p class="form__calendar-title">
            Выберите дату посещения
        </p>
        <div id="datepicker" class="datepicker-here" data-inline="true"></div>
    </div>
```

Срипт:

```
$(".datepicker-here").datepicker( "option", "onSelect", function (dt) {
    console.log('lolkekcheburek');
});
```

Но в консоль не выводится ничего. Пробовала инициализировать карту вручную - все равно провал. Пробовала вместе с  использовать  - все равно провал. Подскажите, в каком месте я допускаю ошибку? Спасибо!

Comment: `$(".datepicker-here").datepicker( { onSelect: function () { console.log("^_^"); }, } );` — пробуйте так...

Comment: Нет, так тоже не работает... :(

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас какие-то ошибки, не связанные с данной библиотекой.

Пример из документации, который работает.

```js
$('.datepicker-here').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(fd) {
    console.log(fd)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-0prQxFtdWQNa3vW5JDMbvbBp6ehKzf9UIWqFGZIWPPE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-q0wZgzQ6Ru67x+pIe9IAztrnlHNHyZui3BMwqUYDnpI=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<input type='text' class="datepicker-here" data-inline="true" />
```